# How to configure hibernate-entitymanager:4.3.8.Final to work with SLF4J?

Tags: spring, hibernate, slf4j

I recently changed the `hibernate-entitymanager` version from `4.0.1` to `4.3.8.Fianl`, after that I got this error when I deployed project to WildFly:

```
12:17:15,340 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-5) log4j:ERROR A "org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator" object is not assignable to a "org.apache.log4j.spi.Configurator" variable.
12:17:15,341 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-5) log4j:ERROR The class "org.apache.log4j.spi.Configurator" was loaded by 
12:17:15,341 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-5) log4j:ERROR [ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.taolijie.war:main" from Service Module Loader] whereas object of type 
12:17:15,342 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-5) log4j:ERROR "org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator" was loaded by [ModuleClassLoader for Module "org.jboss.log4j.logmanager:main" from local module loader @12bc6874 (finder: local module finder @de0a01f (roots: /home/whf/app/wildfly-8.0.0.Final/modules,/home/whf/app/wildfly-8.0.0.Final/modules/system/layers/base))].
12:17:15,342 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-5) log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate configurator [org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator].
12:17:15,347 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-5) log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.jboss.logging).
12:17:15,348 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-5) log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
12:17:15,348 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-5) log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

If I change the version of `hinbernate-entitymanager` back to `4.0.1`, everything is fine.
I have no idea about this.. How to fix?

Here is my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <!--<version>4.0.1.Final</version>-->
            <version>4.3.8.Final</version>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.16</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wildfly 8.2 if I'm not wrong already includes this version of hibernate entity manager so change your dependency scope to provided it should work fine, and change the hibernate core dependency to provided if you have it in your pom, hibernate will include the libs at runtime for you.